# Why is my image slideshow not displaying the slideshow correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm working on a website project and I wanted to create an image carousel. The problem I'm having is that the images aren't showing up and I don't know why.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000);
}
```

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("../background1.jpg");
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: white;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: deeppink;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: pink;
}
/*Slideshow container*/

.mySlides {
  display: none
}
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}
/*Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
/* Position right next button */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
/*Number text*/

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
/*The indicators*/

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
/*Fading animation*/

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome to Fazbear Entertainment</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fnaf.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fnaf.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#FFB6C1">
    <div class="header">
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Prices</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 5</div>
        <img src="fnafworld.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Welcome to Fazbear Entertainment</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
        <img src="funtimefreddy.png" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Funtime Freddy</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 5</div>
        <img src="funtimefoxy.png" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Funtime Foxy</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">4 / 5</div>
        <img src="baby.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Baby</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">5 / 5</div>
        <img src="Ballora.png" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Ballora</div>
      </div>

      <a class="prev" onClick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onClick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onClick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onClick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onClick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div>
    <br />
  </body>
</html>
```

Sorry this a bit lengthy but I really want to figure out what the problem is. Thank you so much!

Comment: images aren't showing up there can different reasons. Your image src might be incorrect. image may not be present at the url you have specified etc etc. Just verify your image src.

Answer (score 0):

You have this line:

```
<img src="fnafworld.jpg" style="width:100%">
```

If you right click in your slider and want to copy the image path, it will say something like this: `www.yoursite.com/fnafworld.jpg`

You need to be sure that your image is really at this directory. If not, just correct the path.

Could look like this:

```
<img src="resources/images/fnafworld.jpg" style="width:100%">
```